# XapCacheFile.xml Error - Visual Studio - Windows Phone 7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, dropbox

I'm using Dropbox as a place to store my project and update my project from different machines.

Sometimes when I download the project on to a new machine, it doesn't work and it says "Not all files were loaded" etc...

But now on my main machine, it's not working. I receive the following error

```
Error   2   Could not find file 'C:\Users\Usmaan\Dropbox\University\Final Year 
Project\Software\Elementals\Elementals\obj\Debug\XapCacheFile.xml'. Please rebuild the solution and try again.      0   0`
```

What should I do to prevent this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Delete the **obj** and **Bin** folders from the project
2. Rebuild the solution

Comment: Now I just get this error: Xap packaging failed. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3):

Still same problem after obj and bin folders removed.
But this tip was helpful (background image path was not correct in my case)

http://dan.clarke.name/2011/07/msbuild-error-xap-packaging-failed-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object/